# Linux audio loopback: Multichannel to stereo (for OBS usage)

Tags: ubuntu, audio, pulseaudio, loopback

I am using the RME Fireface 802 to record a stereo signal for my stream, but unfortunatly OBS won't accept Multichannel audio that contains more than 8 signals.

So, since OBS doesn't like my multichannel feed, I have to give it a virtual stereo signal.

**My Question:**
How do I create a stereo loopback from 2 selected audio signals from my audio interface?

- Loopback (input) hardware source: 2 Channels on my Multichannel audio interface
- Loopback (virtual input)newly created recording signal: Stereo (L/R) audio signal suitable for OBS

Technical details:
Ubuntu 18.10 with PulseAudio and auvcontrol
OBS 23.1.0 (linux)

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for the undocumented jack client `jack_thru`.  The only docs I *ever* found were in the book [Advanced Audio Visualization Using ThMAD](https://www.google.de/search?tbm=bks&hl=en&q=%22jack_thru%22).  Just enter

```
jack_thru
```

on the command line and you can start connecting to it in QJackCtl.

*Note: I'm currently struggling with a new audio interface, so that's all the information I can give.  But I have successfully used `jack_thru` for internal routing during the last few years.  I'm on Linux Mint 19.3 and `jack_thru` resides in the package **jackd2** (I had to compile `jack_thru` in earlier versions of Linux Mint, though).*